# How can I match/capture the just the opening tag of the outerHTML of an element

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture just the opening tag of an HTML element. I am using element.outerHTML to get the string of text to work with. It works when there is a new line after the opening tag:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(
   div.outerHTML.match(/^<(.*)>/)[1]
);
```

```html
<div id="awesomeID" class="one two three four">
</div>
```

However, when the element is a 1-liner, it breaks and captures all the way to the end of the closing tag:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(
  div.outerHTML.match(/^<(.*)>/)[1]
);
```

```html
<div id="awesomeID" class="one two three four"></div>
```

**How can I get this to only capture the opening tag?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the lazy qualifier `*?` instead of the greedy one `*`.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(
  div.outerHTML.match(/^<(.*?)>/)[1]
);
```

```html
<div id="awesomeID" class="one two three four"></div>
```

The greedy qualifier matches as many occurrences as possible, so it stops at the last possible occurrence. In your example, it stops at the last `>`.

While the lazy qualifier matches as few occurrences as possible, so it stops at the first possible occurrence. In your example, it stops at the first `>`.

Comment: Consider markup as `<div id="awesomeID" data-text="<div>Hey hi</div>" class="one two three four"></div>`...